# how to fix eclipse gc overhead error when launch android application second time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i am facing problem in my eclipse ,when i am launch my android application second time it shows error message . Eclipse GC overhead (Heap memory overhead)

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or log? Please provide that to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on the project 
select RunAs
Run configurations
 
Select your project as BaseDirectory. In place of goals give eclipse:eclipse install
In the second tab give -Xmx1024m as VM arguments.
Another easy way to do this is 
open `eclipse.ini` and increase the Xms (heap’s start memory) and Xmx (heap’s maximum memory) values to a value that you think is reasonable with your system and projects, for example:

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Try this.Let me know if problem still occurs